# Angular JS deep-link and browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an angular-js based single-page solution. I thought my deep-linking was working, forward and back browser history works fine.  But if I refresh (F5) the single record page... bootstrap and angular don't seem to load and the page displays incorrectly.
So I am expecting /owners to provide a list and /owners/XYZ to provide the XYZ single owner record.

The error I receive indicates Chrome is not interpreting this as html - failing on the first css link... but it is deep-linking - when using the browsers history ok. When I refresh I get the error ->>
    Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myfakedomain.com/owners/css/bootstrap.css".

Ok the code - Here I hook up the routeProvider:

```js
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix("!");
$routeProvider
    .when('/owners', {templateUrl: '/partials/owner-list.html',  controller:OwnerListCtrl})
    .when('/owners/:name', {templateUrl: '/partials/owner-details.html',   controller:OwnerCtrl})
     .when('/', {templateUrl:'/partials/home.html', controller:HomeCtrl})
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/home'});
}]);
```

2 simple controllers that are relevant here... the backend is a factory service for retrieval from a RESTful webservice.

```js
function OwnerListCtrl($scope, $routeParams, backend) {
var ug = $( "#ug" ).html();
var mydata = null;

// load the params coming from the UI
if (($routeParams != null)&& ($routeParams.nm != null))
    mydata = $routeParams.nm;
else{
    // in case we get here directly - ensure only super users
    // will access other owner entities
    if (ug != SUPERUSER)
        mydata = $( "#on" ).html();     
}
backend.owners(mydata).then(function (result){
        $scope.owners = result.data.data;
});
$scope.orderProp = 'name';
}
```

And the single record controller...

```js
function OwnerCtrl($scope, $routeParams, $http, backend,$log, $location){
    // populate the companys select dropdown
    $scope.companys=function(){
        backend.companys().then(function (response){
            $scope.companies = response.data.data;
        })
    }
    if (($routeParams == null) && ($routeParams.name == null)){
        var ug = $( "#ug" ).html();
        var myParam = null;

        if (ug != SUPERUSER)
            myParam = $( "#on" ).html();

        backend.owners(myParam).then(function (result){
            $scope.owner = result.data.data[0];
            $scope.companys();
        });
    }else{
        backend.owners($routeParams.name).then(function (result){
            $scope.owner = result.data.data[0];
            $scope.companys();
            $log.info($location.url());
        });     
    }

}
```

Any insights would be welcomed.

Comment: yes - sorry for the slow response - I adopted absolute relative paths with /  rather than a purely relative original ../  for my css references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is a routing issue.  If you look at the path to the css file its attempting to load from myfakedomain.com/owners/css/bootstrap.css, i'm assuming it should be myfakedomain.com/css/bootstrap.css.  Are the paths relatively defined in your html file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use absolute paths for the linked files, js and css both.
You need to set up a .htaccess file in the root directory that rewrites all requests to index.html, assuming that is your angular application. Here is the suggested solution:

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api
#RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# otherwise forward it to index.html
#RewriteRule ^app/(.*) /app/#/$1 [NC,L]
```

However, a simplified version works for me, my application subdirectories are in the root folder, rather than the app folder as in the example. This works for my case

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Hope this helps.